# How to create a object to access a Complex type names in WSDL using savon

Tags: ruby, wsdl, savon

I am a newbie for SAVON and ruby this is my first assignment from my client. So any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<complexType name="CEvent">
 <annotation>
  <documentation>The base used for all events. All events extend this structure.</documentation> 
  </annotation>
 <complexContent>
 <extension base="ttns:CItemWithDBRecordId">
 <sequence>
  <element name="user" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="date" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" /> 
  <element name="notes" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="eventaddorder" type="xsd:short" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" /> 
  <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="parenteventid" type="xsd:long" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" /> 
  <element name="attachmentlist" type="ttns:ArrayOfCFileAttachment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="fieldlist" type="ttns:ArrayOfCField" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="resultingstate" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="hours" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" /> 
  <element name="assigntolist" type="ttns:ArrayOfstring" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="releasenotesversion" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="generatedeventtype" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="generatedbyname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="totaltimespent" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" /> 
  <element name="overrideuser" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" /> 
  <element name="marksuspect" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" /> 
  </sequence>
  </extension>
  </complexContent>
  </complexType>
```

and i dont know how to get that and also need to update the fields of the elements with my input data.

I am accessing it the Complex name this way.

response = @client.request 'CEvent'

and the response that i got is

(SOAP-ENV:Client) Method 'ins0:CEvent' not implemented: method name or namespac
 not recognized

Im sure that this is not the way,as its not a method name , so im still scratching my head to resolve this.!!

Comment: What have you written? We expect you to show us you've done some work toward solving the problem. As is, it looks like you're at the absolute beginning of the task and are already asking for help.

Comment: response = @client.request :CEvent ...this is the way I am accessing sorry for late reply...

Answer (score 0):

I just recently completed a project using SAVON to access SOAP services on Microsoft SharePoint.  You should be able to access the response data using the hash value returned by the Savon request.

response.hash[:annotation][:complexContent][:sequence]

Have a look at the article on my web site below.  It is not specific to your requirement but might help.

http://mark.stratmann.me/content_items/using-savon-to-connect-to-microsoft-sharepoint-soap-services-in-rails-3-2